# Copying file from Vagrant-VM to host failed... connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox

I want to copy file from vagrant machine to my host machine to do that I'm using this command

```
scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/pjsip-build/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyuv.so .
```

but it gives me this error ssh: **connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused**

If i don't mention the port and just run this way

`scp vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/pjsip-build/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyuv.so`

it gives me error **scp : home/vagrant/pjsip-build/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyuv.so: No such file or directory**

So what's going wrong here? how can i copy file from guest to host machine.

**EDIT:** 
 MY ssh configuration is this

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/arfeen/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

and when i do vagrant up  my port forwarding is this

```
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...

        default: Adapter 1: nat
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
        default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)s this
```

Comment: can you run `scp` with verbose mode adding `-v`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

first issue - you probably have no one listening on 2222. it should not say port 22 as the P flag should call the 2222 port.

** after your correction - check that the port is open in iptables if you have blocking and check the sshd is listening on this port:

netstat -l

second - better use the src and dst:

scp vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/pjsip-build/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyuv.so .

(notice the . in the end that means copy to local folder)

and make sure the machine at 127.0.0.1 has the path: /home/vargant.... ect, and the user vargant has access to the so file.

I also can't understand why you use 127.0.0.1 - as this would be your own address. unless you use this to hide the real address of the server in question - or you local card is bridged, and then - did you change the listening port of ssh on the machine to 2222 ?

Comment: yeah it said port 222 not 22, sorry my mistake and I'm also using the . too

Comment: I can't see port 2222 by running netstat -l but there is a port *:ssh

Comment: I think listening port for ssh is set to 2222 because if i run the vagrant ssh-config. I see the port is set to 2222

 HostName : 127.0.0.1
 UserName : Vagrant
 Port : 2222
.
.

Answer (score 0):

when you run `vagrant up` it should give you some indication (this is my own example, the port will differ for you)

```
xxxx
==> jenkins: Setting the name of the VM: jenkins
==> jenkins: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2205.
xxxx
==> jenkins: Forwarding ports...
    jenkins: 22 (guest) => 2205 (host) (adapter 1)
```

In this case it runs ssh port on port 2205 on my host so I would need to run the `scp -P 2205 ....`

You can also review this information by running `vagrant ssh-config``

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host jenkins
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2205
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/fhenri/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Answer (score 0):

If your vagrant VM is running on your host machine (a.k.a. there's just one computer involved) you can transfer files by placing them in the "Synced folder" within vagrant.

When vagrant provisions a virtual machine, by default it links the `/vagrant` folder to whatever folder the vagrant file is located in. And by linked, I mean the `/vagrant` folder on the virtual machine contains all of the same stuff as the `Vagrantfile` folder on the host machine. Copying any files to that folder from either machine will make those files available on both machines.

By editing your vagrant file, you can add other folders that are synced in this manner. You can learn more by reading the vagrant docs on the topic here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/